# How to draw an ordered tree in python?

Tags: python, graph, tree

I have an XML file whose underlying structure is an ordered tree. I use digraph in networks representing this tree and then I want to draw this tree. Suppose the digraph is G, then I write the following code:

```
map = dict(zip(id,tag)) # map from id to label
pos = nx.pydot_layout(G,prog = 'dot')
labels = nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos, map) 
nx.draw_networkx(G, pos, False, node_size = 1000, node_color = color)
plt.show()
```

but i cannot get a ordered tree. the order of silbing nodes are not in their original order.

I want to know how can I plot an ordered tree in python, thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Don't call a variable `map`, there is a builtin called `map`.

You can use an [OrderedDict](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) to keep the items in order:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
from itertools import izip
themap = OrderedDict(izip(id,tag)) # map from id to label
```

You can also [get it from PyPI](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/ordereddict) if you have an older version of Python than 2.7 / 3.2.

Comment: Thanks, I really shouldn't name a variable map. but I still don't know how to draw this ordered tree. draw_networkx doesn't give me the right tree

Comment: You'll have to give more detain that "not the right tree". Try making a much smaller tree that's got the same basic structure and try that, so you can figure out what's wrong.